# Install pytorch version 1.0.0 using pip or cuda in 2023

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I want to install the pytoch version 1.0.0, but i couldn't able to do that

I tried

```
pip install torch===1.0.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

its not wotking I'm getting a error

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch===1.0.0 (from versions: 1.7.1, 1.7.1+cpu, 1.7.1+cu101, 1.7.1+cu110, 1.7.1+cu92, 1.7.1+rocm3.7, 1.7.1+rocm3.8, 1.8.0, 1.8.0+cpu, 1.8.0+cu101, 1.8.0+cu111, 1.8.0+rocm3.10, 1.8.0+rocm4.0.1, 1.8.1, 1.8.1+cpu, 1.8.1+cu101, 1.8.1+cu102, 1.8.1+cu111, 1.8.1+rocm3.10, 1.8.1+rocm4.0.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.0+cpu, 1.9.0+cu102, 1.9.0+cu111, 1.9.0+rocm4.0.1, 1.9.0+rocm4.1, 1.9.0+rocm4.2, 1.9.1, 1.9.1+cpu, 1.9.1+cu102, 1.9.1+cu111, 1.9.1+rocm4.0.1, 1.9.1+rocm4.1, 1.9.1+rocm4.2, 1.10.0, 1.10.0+cpu, 1.10.0+cu102, 1.10.0+cu111, 1.10.0+cu113, 1.10.0+rocm4.0.1, 1.10.0+rocm4.1, 1.10.0+rocm4.2, 1.10.1, 1.10.1+cpu, 1.10.1+cu102, 1.10.1+cu111, 1.10.1+cu113, 1.10.1+rocm4.0.1, 1.10.1+rocm4.1, 1.10.1+rocm4.2, 1.10.2, 1.10.2+cpu, 1.10.2+cu102, 1.10.2+cu111, 1.10.2+cu113, 1.10.2+rocm4.0.1, 1.10.2+rocm4.1, 1.10.2+rocm4.2, 1.11.0, 1.11.0+cpu, 1.11.0+cu102, 1.11.0+cu113, 1.11.0+cu115, 1.11.0+rocm4.3.1, 1.11.0+rocm4.5.2, 1.12.0, 1.12.0+cpu, 1.12.0+cu102, 1.12.0+cu113, 1.12.0+cu116, 1.12.0+rocm5.0, 1.12.0+rocm5.1.1, 1.12.1, 1.12.1+cpu, 1.12.1+cu102, 1.12.1+cu113, 1.12.1+cu116, 1.12.1+rocm5.0, 1.12.1+rocm5.1.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.0+cpu, 1.13.0+cu116, 1.13.0+cu117, 1.13.0+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 1.13.0+rocm5.1.1, 1.13.0+rocm5.2, 1.13.1, 1.13.1+cpu, 1.13.1+cu116, 1.13.1+cu117, 1.13.1+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 1.13.1+rocm5.1.1, 1.13.1+rocm5.2, 2.0.0, 2.0.0+cpu, 2.0.0+cpu.cxx11.abi, 2.0.0+cu117, 2.0.0+cu117.with.pypi.cudnn, 2.0.0+cu118, 2.0.0+rocm5.3, 2.0.0+rocm5.4.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch===1.0.0
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip install torch==1.0.0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your Python3 version is newer (>3.7) than what the version of torch you're trying to install supports.

Available versions of torch start from 1.7.1. Consider using an older version of Python3 (<=3.7).

To do this, I recommend installing conda or miniconda from [here](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).

Then, run:

`conda create -n myenv python=3.6.9`

Load your env:

`conda activate myenv`

Try install torch again:

`pip install torch===1.0.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Try out this one.

```
pip install torch==1.0.0
```

Actually, the one which you were trying had three equals(=).

```
pip install torch===1.0.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

That's why it was not working.